# Gatsby - create index.js in every subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

My Gatsby site sources its content from YAML files rather than Markdown. There are a bunch of categories and subcategories, such that valid paths are like:

```
mysite.com/movies/drama/war/1980s
mysite.com/video-games/puzzles
etc...
```

I would like to create an `index.js` for every subdirectory: /movies , /movies/drama, /movies/drama/war, /video-games, etc.

My strategy is to get a list of all the pages, from which I can extract all the unique paths and `createPage` an index.js in each. However I tried querying

```
  {
    allSitePage {
      nodes {
        path
      }
    }
  }
```

during gatsby-node's `createPages` but none of the paths had been created yet -- only the root and 404 paths existed (probably because these are the only files in my /pages directory?)

I'm guessing there's a better way to do this anyway. How can I create an index.js in every subdirectory? Thank you.

**EDIT:** I realized `createPage` is an asyncronous function, my query was running before the `createPage`s had completed. I adjusted all my code with async/await to ensure the pages were created prior to running the `allSitePage` query -- but it still comes up empty. Now really confused. (Another note: in the GraphiQL browser, the query of course shows all the pages. They just don't seem to be available until after `gatsby-node.js` completes)

**2nd EDIT**: I was asked to post my createPage() code:

```
  const postsYaml = resultYaml.data.allYaml.edges
  // 1-1 mapping between YAML edge and Gatsby page
  // use Promise.all() to ensure all pages are created before continuing
  await Promise.all(postsYaml.map(async (post, index) => {
    const previous = index === postsYaml.length - 1 ? null : postsYaml[index + 1].node
    const next = index === 0 ? null : postsYaml[index - 1].node

    createPage({
      path: post.node.fields.slug,
      component: blog-page,
      context: {
        slug: post.node.fields.slug,
        previous,
        next
      },
    })
  }))
```

So this code runs, creates the pages, then I execute the GraphQL I originally posted -- and the pages aren't there.

Comment: `I'm guessing there's a better way to do this anyway. How can I create an index.js in every subdirectory?` - No, createPage is just the right function. In my project it creates a /blog/2019-09-09-blog-post hierarchy and at the end there is an index.html. Please supply your `createPage` function in your `gatsby-node.js`.

Comment: I've added the code. The reason I thought there's a "better way" is because even if I get the GraphQL to execute correctly, it's still quite messy having to filter the list of all posts/pages for each individual subdirectory, likely requiring regex to match paths with page slugs. Further, this seems like a pretty common scenario, wanting index pages at the root of every subdirectory.

Comment: Hard to debug without having access to the code. Does it work with only one single yaml source file? Is the component `blog-page` working correctly? Is the structure there when you `gatsby build` and `gatsby serve`? Can you explore the GraphQL graph in the browser GarphiQL interface?

Comment: In this case a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example might be useful.

Comment: Yes all the YAML files properly get matched with a template and pages are all created successfully. Yes the `allSitePage` query works 100% fine in GraphiQL. I've built a workaround that skips the query, although I can't access to the YAML metadata. A minimal example would be load a starter kit, insert the `allSiteQuery` from my code into the bottom of `gatsby-node.js` and see if the query comes up empty. It does for me. Ultimately I believe the primary question is: *when does `allSitePage` get populated?*, because it doesn't seem to happen within `gatsby-node.js`

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant your help is appreciated but I don't think we'll reach a conclusion here, there's no way to isolate a snippet of code, you need a minimal gatsby installation to reproduce